# Lost my project folder after updating Android Studio 3.0.2 to 3.6.1, how can I recover it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, projects-and-solutions, android-studio-3.6

I have updated my Android Studio version from 3.0.2 to 3.6.1 and during the update, it asks me to delete old files like `.AndroidStudio2.1 .AndroidStudio2.2 .AndroidStudio2.3 .AndroidStudio3.1 .AndroidStudio3.2` to free up some space I select and delete this file then after the update my project folder is deleted I cant see my old project file in that drive.

How can I recover my project folder? It contains an approx 150 project file.

Comment: Are you using version control, like Git for example?

Comment: Yes, I am using Git. But in Git I have uploaded only few project.

Answer (score 0):

we discovered that the default folder moved.  Have you tried opening from the "recent" menu?   If you know the name of one of them, you could search your hard drive.  Even if you deleted the old folder when you upgraded and for some reason your projects were in a folder in there, it's put in the recycle bin.  I can't help you more than that as the location is different depending on the OS you have.

Comment: Yes I tried to open project from recent menu but it is showing no file found and I had also check in hard drive and recycle bin.